# Magento "Use Defualt Value" mass update

Tags: magento, default

Another Magento Question,
Can anyone help me with this? im trying to specify a range of product_id's to update attributes to set the flag "USE DEFAULT VALUE", yet i keep getting errors i think i'm trying to set the range in the wrong way.

```
<?php
 include_once '.../app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

 $prods = range(5490,5495);

 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->load($prods)
 ->setStoreId(1)
 ->setData('status', false)
 ->setData('name', false)
 ->setData('short_description', false)
 ->save();
echo "successful";
 ?>
```

When i run this version with help from Daniel S,

```
<?php
include_once '/home/sites/billyguyatts.com.au/docs/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$prods = range(5492,5498);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $prods))
->load();

$productCollection
->setStoreId(1)    
->setDataToAll('status', false)
->setDataToAll('name', false)
->setDataToAll('short_description', false)
->save();
echo "successful";
?>
```

i get successful echo but no result, when i run it with

```
    $productCollection->setDataToAll('status', false)
    ->setData('name', false)
 ->setData('short_description', false)
    ->save();
```

I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection::setData()

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a single model to load several products. Use a collection:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $prods))
    ->load();

$productCollection->setDataToAll('status', false)
                  ->...
                  ->...
                  ->save();
```

Comment: Thank, for your answer. As you can see im hopeless at php, unfortunately i still cant get this to work, not sure if it is the attribute filter or  the setdatatoall that is making it fail.